# Where did half my rep points go on that question?

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

On my "reputation" page I see this:

```
+25      42 secs ago    5 votes  How do I add a button beside each node of a TreeView?
```

5 votes, +25? That does not compute. So I click to expand, and this is what I see:

```
             20:13  upvote   
             20:08  upvote   
+5           20:06  upvote   
+10          20:05  upvote   
+10          20:05  upvote
```

Half upvotes? And blank upvotes? Huh?

[On the question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672735/how-do-i-add-a-button-beside-each-node-of-a-treeview/8672802#8672802) it says that I have 5 upvotes.

Comment: Look into the rep cap. You can earn +200 from upvotes in a given day, the +15 for accepted answers and +X from bounties do not count towards the cap. Every upvote after 200 rep is donated to the screen actors guild.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Oh, okay, thank you, and sorry for bothering you about this. Should I delete this question?

Comment: From what I've found though, he's only at 192 reputation for the day (+45 for accepts)... Can someone check my calculations?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted a few today, but not 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, you have received [237 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773113/mikenakis?tab=reputation). Your reputation gain minus approved edits and accepted answers is 237 - 12 - 45 = 180 (= reputation from upvotes).

The daily reputation cap from **upvotes only** is 200. You have probably deleted a question/answer, causing the reputation mutation to be invisible at the [Reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773113/mikenakis?tab=reputation).

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and scroll to the bottom to see today's calculations.

Comment: Don't edits still count towards the reputation cap?

Comment: @animuson The reputation cap is only affected by upvotes.

Comment: I'm not sure about that; a few days ago we had a "serial minor editor" who had hundreds of edits, but was capped at 200 rep from them.